# How do I add an empty attribute to stylesheet_link_tag "application"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html, attributes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How do I add an empty attribute to `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>`?

I want to add `data-skrollr-stylesheet` emty attribute  to it, so the output html would be:

```
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-skrollr-stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with the helper. `stylesheet_link_tag` ends up calling `tag`, which renders the options using the [`tag_options`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/39b9c943b7ec5181c19461d319d8c610ea1bf941/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb#L135) method:

```
def tag_options(options, escape = true)
  unless options.blank?
    attrs = []
    options.each_pair do |key, value|
      if key.to_s == 'data' && value.is_a?(Hash)
        value.each do |k, v|
          unless v.is_a?(String) || v.is_a?(Symbol) || v.is_a?(BigDecimal)
            v = v.to_json
          end
          v = ERB::Util.html_escape(v) if escape
          attrs << %(data-#{k.to_s.dasherize}="#{v}")
        end
      elsif BOOLEAN_ATTRIBUTES.include?(key)
        attrs << %(#{key}="#{key}") if value
      elsif !value.nil?
        final_value = value.is_a?(Array) ? value.join(" ") : value
        final_value = ERB::Util.html_escape(final_value) if escape
        attrs << %(#{key}="#{final_value}")
      end
    end
    " #{attrs.sort * ' '}".html_safe unless attrs.empty?
  end
end
```

Notice that options are always rendered in a `key=value` fashion.

You can, however, render the attribute with an empty string:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all", :data => {'skrollr-stylesheet' => ''} %>
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe such a thing was so complex!

Comment: I'm not sure for what purpose "BOOLEAN_ATTRIBUTES.include?(key)" stands for. I ended up deleting it and it works!